# Condition Inside Count Function Using Case In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have one table having two columns named OrderId and OrderType

```
OrderId OrderType
------- ---------
1       Drawer
2       Pickup
3       Delivery
4       Delivery
5       Drawer
```

In my stored procedure I want to pass the argument of `OrderType` which would return a result only on matching `OrderType` Column data to the argument i.e. if I pass the argument 'Drawer' then it should return count of `OrderType` column where `OrderType` column data is 'Drawer' and so on.

How can i do that using `Count`?

Currently I am doing:

```
select @tempvar1=case @tempvar
when 'Drawer'
Then Count(CASE_TABLE.OrderType) --What Should i put here to get desired result?
end
select @tempvar1
```

Instead of counting the whole column I want only the count matching `OrderType`.

Comment: Are you asking where to use a `WHERE` clause to get your specific data? If so use a `WHERE` clause after your second select like you would in a normal query.

Comment: No i am asking What should i put in count to get the desired matching data instead of counting whole column rows

Comment: See @MattJohnson answer below. It look like it does what you want with `Count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd so something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @argument VARCHAR(9) = 'Drawer'

SELECT
  OrderType,
  COUNT(OrderType) AS [Count]
FROM
  [Order]
WHERE
  OrderType = @argument
GROUP BY
  OrderType
```

**Results**

```
OrderType Count
--------- -----
Drawer    2
```

You can test it out at SqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcff9/2).

Comment: This is assuming SQL Server 2008+ (the `DECLARE` statement)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke SP:-

```
Exec GetOrderType 'Drawer'
```

SP:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderType
     @OrderType nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        your_table_name
    WHERE
        OrderType = @OrderType
    GROUP BY
        OrderType

END
GO
```